# Database consistency check using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, validation, stored-procedures

I have the next problem:

The database in the system has denormalized tables with lets say "CompanyID" field held on almost every table in the database. This was done due to business rules purposes and should be that way. Sometimes the data is inconsistent as the Customer being with CompanyID == 1 has the order with CompanyID == 2.

My suggestion is to write specialized stored procedure which would be fired every once in a while and analyse some basic 'relation chains' on this property (meaning Cusomer with some Company ID should always have only Orders from the same Company ID where the latter has Articles with corresponding Company ID)

Quesqion:

Is there any generic way in SQL to fetch tables having field CompanyID and then checking them on consistency? Any other solutions to this problem?

I get the tables with the given column name using this SQL:

```
select column_name, c.is_nullable, c.table_schema, c.table_name, t.table_type, t.table_catalog, * 
from information_schema.columns c join information_schema.tables t 
on c.table_schema = t.table_schema and c.table_name = t.table_name 
where column_name = 'CompanyID' 
and table_type not in ('VIEW') 
and t.table_name not like 'MsMerge%' 
order by ordinal_position
```

After that I have in mind to traverse by foreign keys up the relation tree for record checking the equality of the CompanyID parameter.

Comment: what is the rdbms? oracle? sql server? postgresql? mysql?

Comment: Business rules don't determine denormalisation, since the entire point of a denormalised schema is that it holds the same data as a normalised schema, but in a format which can be accessed more quickly; albeit at the cost of increased difficulty in maintaining data integrity - as seen here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not do that via a generic sql that runs every view minutes - this is the performance dead for big databases.

Instead you could use a Insert/Update Trigger on every effected table that you would code like that:

```
CREATE TRIGGER chk_tablename
ON T1 tablename 
FOR INSERT,UPDATE
AS
BEGIN

  // Your checks are here
  // Log inconsistent data

END
```

Comment: yeah. good point. should discuss it with my team. I like it a lot better then having stored procedures do some strange logic.

Answer (score 1):

example of query:

```
lets say these are our tables:
create table customer(
id int, 
companyID int
)

create table orders (
orderId int, 
customerid int, 
companyID int --"wrong column"
)
```

you should tun queries like these:

```
update orders
set companyID=(select companyID from customer where id=customerid)
```

to correct the data, but also eliminate all usages of column companyID  on table orders.

If you have loads of places where this is happening and you want to create an automate way of running the above query, you can look for the column companyID on the table `sys.columns`, get the table name from it and build a loop to generate the queries

EDIT (based on your answer on the comments):

so the logic is pretty much the same. 
Loop through the sys.columns table to get the tables  where the column appears and for each table run:

```
select * 
from orders o
where companyID != (select companyID from customer where id=customerid)
```

Comment: well the thing is I don't want to correct the data, I want only to detect this inconsistency and return table name with record primary key that would spot the problem and will let me decide later what to do with this data.